# Why am I getting an "ERR" while using my Nikon 50mm 1.4G lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, 50mm, error

I'm using a Nikon D610. In the middle of shooting a wedding I switched from my Nikon 50mm 1.4G to my Nikon 70-200mm 2.4. When switching back to the 50mm, any aperture smaller than 2.2 would result in "err" flashing on the camera.

I can shoot fine with wide apertures 1.4 up to 2 on the 50mm, but at 2.2 it results in the err along with anything higher. Switching back to the 70-200mm everything is fine.

Any thoughts? Both body and lens are fairly new.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your aperture ring in the automatic position?

Comment: It's a new 50mm f/1.4G AF-S, not sure exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for this issue and people are suggesting you clean the contacts of the lens. If this does not work there is nothing you can do except contact a service center.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I've cleaned both contacts with a microfibre cloths, guess i'll be taking it in.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have bent the aperture lever in the camera body that contacts the aperture lever on the back of the lens. Or you may have bent the lever on the back of the lens that the camera's lever pushes to stop down the aperture just before the shutter opens. This is a fairly common problem when changing lenses on cameras that still use mechanical, rather than electrical, aperture control. It's easy to do if the lens isn't lined up properly when you twist the lens on the camera.

You might also have pressured something into misalignment that is causing some of the electrical contacts between the lens and camera to not line up properly. Normally in such a case, though, the lens wouldn't work at any aperture other than (perhaps) wide open.

For more about mechanical aperture levers and electrically controlled apertures, please see:
[Nikon D5200 overexposed shots in "auto" modes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/72413/15871)
[This answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/54252/15871) to [What are the dangers of removing a lens while the camera is on?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6217/15871)
[What is an electromagnetic diaphragm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65543/15871)
[Inconsistent exposure with same settings--why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/60591/15871)
[I changed my camera lens while my camera was on](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/44048/15871)
[Nikon D7000 thinks aperture of non-cpu lens is always 16 and overexposes photos](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/58045/15871)

For other possible causes with Nikon cameras, please see:

[Using an external battery pack with my Nikon d5200 caused glitches](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92422/15871)
[Nikon D90 mirror stuck](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/74780/15871)
[How to fix Nikon D40x shutter not re-arming?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/49483/15871)

Comment: Thanks! If this is a new 50mm f/1.4G AF-S, wouldn't it be electrical aperture control? It seems the issue would like be the misalignment of electrical contacts. As it does only work with a few wide apertures.

Comment: If it was an electrical aperture controlled Nikon lens, it would be named 50mm f/1.4E, rather than 50mm f/1.4G. I am not aware of any such lens. The electrical contacts in 'G' lenses communicate the lens ID and other information, but they don't actually control how the aperture is stopped down when the picture is taken. The system of mechanical levers still does that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same camera and same lenses (and it was caused the same way!). I compared the lever on my D610 to the one on my D800 and the D610's was definitely bent a little. I fixed it slowly by literally using my finger to push the aperture lever back to its proper position. Originally, only f/1.4 worked, but I slowly gained access to smaller apertures over time with more pushing.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I had a fairly new 50mm loaned to me recently, (using a D4s).
I thought I'd just whack the new lens on & charge off into the sunset ! 
Man o man, wrong!
In desperation, I set it up like it was an old series lens, & it worked !
Fingers crossed this will work for you.

Turn camera off.
Then turn the aperture right up to the biggest/highest F stop number.
Turn camera back on.
Hopefully it will work fine now.

Comment: This is a "G" lens. It doesn't have an aperture ring.

Comment: It is great that your answer is intended as helpful advice. However it does not have much objective technical content relevant to the particular problem.